# Inline list vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I cant figure out why my list is not vertically aligned. I set `ul` and `li` to be 100% height of parent, but it seems to be only 100% of itself.

I dont want to use any margin or padding to make them vertically aligned. How can I force it to be 100% of parent so it would be vertically in the middle?

http://jsfiddle.net/qS5A6/

Comment: do you mean centred vertically?

Comment: do you mean centred vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#nav li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    line-height:90px; //add this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

defining your height relative to the parten usually just works with elements that have `position:absolute`. The reason is, that the height of surrounding elements is usually determined by their children. If you make the childrens height relative to the parent you have an endless loop :)

So using this code would make your li have 100% height but the height of your #nav won't change anymore with increasing length of the ul.

http://jsfiddle.net/qS5A6/5/

Using display: table instead of your inline-block approach would keep that functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/qS5A6/6/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use table-cell for li:

```
#nav ul{    
    display: table;    
    height: 90px;
}

#nav li{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this works fine for ie8+ 
if you use:

```
#nav li a{
     line-height:90px;
}
```

there is some problem, you can't have more, than one line in the tag